# Where I can find opencv.js with solvePnP or how to build it?

Tags: javascript, opencv, opencv-solvepnp

Hello guys) I need function solvePnP from opencv in opencv.js.
But I can't find version with solvepnp included.
Could you, please, help me to find opencv.js version with solvePnP or build it? Do you know where I can find solvePnP in other js library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options. The easiest is to install [mjyc's fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mjyc/opencv.js) using `npm`:

```
$ npm i @mjyc/opencv.js
```

or install directly [version `4.0.1`](https://github.com/mjyc/opencv/archive/4.0.1.zip) directly from the [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/mjyc/opencv/releases).

In your js:

```
const opencv = require('@mjyc/opencv.js');
opencv.solvePnP();
```

Please note that mjyc's fork is behind (4.0.1) OpenCV's own repository, which is currently at 4.5.1.

Alternatively you can install OpenCV by downloading it from the [GitHub release page](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases), then install one of the javascript bindings:

1. [peterbraden's Node bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv)
2. [justadudewhohacks' Node bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs)

There are a few others available [on npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=opencv).

Comment: Thank you for answer!) I install it from npm and then copy opencv.js from node_modules to my project.

Comment: This one is updated also [@techstark/opencv-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@techstark/opencv-js)

Comment: @ffletcherr are you sure that one includes solvePnP? I don't see it there